# Get parent component's elementRef from child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`. Parent component uses `ng-content` so it can have anything within and in any kind of DOM element hierarchy.

My child component has a specific requirement:

> 1. When *child* is clicked it toggles the display of its details
> 2. When *child* is placed inside `ParentComponent`, then when the *parent* is clicked, *child* should do the same as in 1.

Since parent can have any content it seems unreasonable to add `@ContentChild` to the parent, because ... well encapsulation.

So the only place where this should handled is `ChildComponent`. Getting to `ParentComponent` is pretty easy by:

```
// ChildComponent ctor
constructor(@Optional() parent: ParentComponent) { ... }
```

but this doesn't help as I need parent component's `ElementRef` so that I would be able to attach a click event handler to it.

**How can I obtain it the Angular way?** <sup>**†**</sup>

> <sup>**†**</sup> *I know I could get `ChildComponent`'s `ElementRef` and traverse the DOM upwards looking for the closest `ParentComponent`'s element, but that's likely more of a hack than the proper Angular way of doing this. I'm pretty sure there must be some better way.*

Comment: Hmmm. What if you attach the Child Component to the parent, and add the event handler to the parent, not the child. Then, whenever the parent is clicked, you trigger the child's handler that should be trigger on click? That's the easiest way I can think of.

Comment: (What i mean is that both the child and parent would have their own event handlers)

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta can you be more specific? Please write an answer and possibly a stackblitz with a running example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATM 2 ideas come to my mind:

**1) Inject the parent component into the child as an optional parameter:**

For this case, the parent should expose the elementRef instance through a public member.

**Pros**:

- Easy to implement

**Contras**:

- Tight coupling of child to parent: What if now you have N-types of parent? Would you define N-Optional properties in the child constructor? Use a base class for all the parents? In which case you will have to use an explicit provider at component level on all the N-Parent components.

**2) Share a service instance across parent and child for tracking click events**

In this case, both parent and child share a common instance of a service that would more or less look like this:

```
export class ClickTracker {
   private readonly _clicks$ = new Subject<void>();
   readonly clicks$ = this._clicks$.asObservable();

   ngOnDestroy(){
      this._click$.complete();
   }

   click(){
      this._clicks$.next(); 
   }
}
```

Basically, both parent and child can emit new events through the `click` method. They can also subscribe to that stream by using the public `clicks$` stream and run logic on events.

For the instance to be shared across the DOM hierarchy, a new instance of the ClickTracker class has to be provided at parent component level:

```
@Component({
  providers: [ClickTracker]
})
export class FooParent{}
```

The hierarchical dependency injector will take care of providing a child component contained in `FooParent` with the `ClickTracker` instance from the parent.

**Pros:**

- No tight coupling between child and parent(s)

**Contras:**

- Parents are now responsible of creating a new service.

Comment: I think solution #2 is too broad, as clicks may get fired by whatever component i.e. sibling component to my child and that would be undesirable. It would also be tricky if the same component would be firing clicks and also subscribe to handle them... Since I only have one specific parent component that I need to have additional behaviour I think the easiest nad best way would be #1.